# Matching Regex with # character

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the following string:

```
style #
```

My regex is as follows:

```
^\s*\b(style #)\b\s*$
```

This is not matching my string.

If I try this regex:

```
^\s*\b(style n)\b\s*$
```

It matches the following string:

```
style n
```

This leads me to think that I am using the `#` character incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\b` means a word boundary (with a letter/number/underscore on exactly one side), and your string doesn't have a word boundary after the `#` (because it's not followed by a letter/number/underscore). Just drop that part.

```
^\s*\b(style #)\s*$
```

(And you actually don't need the first `\b`, either, since the context guarantees there'll be a word boundary there.)